# JQgrid is not showing rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Here is the Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "/Movies/GetAllMovies",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "GET",               
            colNames: ["Id", "Title", "Director", "Date"],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', sorttype: "int" },
                { name: 'Title', index: 'Title', sortable: false },
                { name: 'Director', index: 'Director', sortable: false },
                { name: 'ReleaseDate', index: 'ReleaseDate', align: "right", sortable: false }
            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            pager: "#pager",
            rowNum: 5,
            rownumbers: true,
            rowList: [5, 10, 15],
            height: 'auto',
            width: '500',              
            caption: "My first grid",
        });
    });


</script>
```

and the method which return the list of data is

```
 [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetAllMovies()
    {
        var jsonObj = Json(movieAccessLayer.GetAllMovies());
        return Json(jsonObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);           
    }
```

response string:

```
[{"Id":66,"Title":"BibUtt","Director":"Amal Neeradh","ReleaseDate":"2006-12-12T00:00:00"},{"Id":67,"Title":"Rojaa","Director":"ManiRathnam","ReleaseDate":"1992-05-11T00:00:00"},{"Id":71,"Title":"dwed","Director":"ece","ReleaseDate":"2012-12-12T00:00:00"},{"Id":72,"Title":"Test","Director":"qqwqww","ReleaseDate":"2015-02-09T00:00:00"}]
```

But the problem is: JQgrid and the header row is displaying but the remaining rows are not showing. The controller method is also correct and it will return a list of object.

[image: JQgrid]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you posted not exact the data which returns the controller. You call `Json` **twice** which is the first error. The **jsonObj** have already `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` type. So it have the required data inside of `Data` property. Then you use `Json(jsonObj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` which wraps the returned results and the `GetAllMovies` will returns the data like

```json
{
    "ContentEncoding":null,
    "ContentType":null,
    "Data":[{"Id":66,"Title":"BibUtt",...},...],
    "JsonRequestBehavior":1,
    "MaxJsonLength":null,
    "RecursionLimit":null
}
```

instead of JSON data which you posted. So you should fix the code of `GetAllMovies` to the following

```cs
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAllMovies()
{
    return Json(movieAccessLayer.GetAllMovies(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

After the fix you should already see the results. I would recommend you to make additionally some simple changes in the code which creates the grid. For example

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "/Movies/GetAllMovies",
    datatype: "json",
    loadonce: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    jsonReader: { id: "Id" },
    colNames: ["Id", "Title", "Director", "Date"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "Id", sorttype: "int" },
        { name: "Title" },
        { name: "Director" },
        { name: "ReleaseDate", align: "right", formatter: "date", sorttype: "date" }
    ],
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 5,
    rownumbers: true,
    rowList: [5, 10, "10000:All"],
    height: "auto",
    width: 500,              
    caption: "My first grid",
});
```